# I’m stunned: weird problem with python and sockets + threads

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, sockets

I have a python script that is a http-server: http://paste2.org/p/89701, when benchmarking it against ApacheBench (ab) with a concurrency level (-c switch) that is lower then or equal to the value i specified in the socket.listen()-call in the sourcecode everything works fine, but as soon as put the concurrency level in apache bench above the value in the socket.listen()-call performance drops through the floor, some example:

- socket.listen(**10**) and ab -n 50 -c **10** http://localhost/ = **1200req/s**
- socket.listen(**10**) and ab -n 50 -c **11** http://localhost/ = **40req/s**
- socket.listen(**100**) and ab -n 5000 -c **100** http://localhost/ = **1000req/s**
- socket.listen(**100**) and ab -n 5000 -c **101** http://localhost/ = **32req/s**

Nothing changes in the code between the two calls, I can’t figure out what is wrong - been at this problem for one day now. Also note that: The multiplexing version of the same code (I wrote to compare to the threaded version) works FINE no matter what socket.listen() is set to or what the concurrency (-c switch) in apache is set to.

*I've spent a day on IRC/python docs, posted on comp.lang.python and on my blog - I can't find ANYONE that even has an idea what could be wrong. Help me!*

Comment: Please add what versions of *everything* (Python, OS, etc) you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot confirm your results, and your server is coded fishy. I whipped up my own server and do not have this problem either. Let's move the discussion to a simpler level:

```
import thread, socket, Queue

connections = Queue.Queue()
num_threads = 10
backlog = 10

def request():
    while 1:
        conn = connections.get()
        data = ''
        while '\r\n\r\n' not in data:
            data += conn.recv(4048)
        conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello World')
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        thread.start_new_thread(request, ())

    acceptor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    acceptor.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    acceptor.bind(('', 1234))
    acceptor.listen(backlog)
    while 1:
        conn, addr = acceptor.accept()
        connections.put(conn)
```

which on my machine does:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:1234/ --> 8695.03 [#/sec]
ab -n 10000 -c 11 http://127.0.0.1:1234/ --> 8529.41 [#/sec]
```

Comment: Florian: Awesome, the server is coded so that each thread itself is multiplexing also able to handle and arbitrary number of connections async. But you did shine some light on how to structure it better, thanks a lot. I'll look into rewriting the code matching your example more closeley.

Comment: Also in my version each thread is multiplexing within itself, instead of reading one request blockingly as in yours, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: That's an interesting question, I don't know. You could try removing that multiplexing from your version and test.

Answer (score 4):

For the heck of it I also implemented an asynchronous version:

```
import socket, Queue, select

class Request(object):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.fileno = conn.fileno
        self.perform = self._perform().next

    def _perform(self):
        data = self.conn.recv(4048)
        while '\r\n\r\n' not in data:
            msg = self.conn.recv(4048)
            if msg:
                data += msg
                yield
            else:
                break
        reading.remove(self)
        writing.append(self)

        data = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello World'
        while data:
            sent = self.conn.send(data)
            data = data[sent:]
            yield
        writing.remove(self)
        self.conn.close()

class Acceptor:
    def __init__(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind(('', 1234))
        sock.listen(10)
        self.sock = sock
        self.fileno = sock.fileno

    def perform(self):
        conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
        reading.append(Request(conn))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reading = [Acceptor()]
    writing = list()

    while 1:
        readable, writable, error = select.select(reading, writing, [])
        for action in readable + writable:
            try: action.perform()
            except StopIteration: pass
```

which performs:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:1234/ --> 16822.13 [#/sec]
ab -n 10000 -c 11 http://127.0.0.1:1234/ --> 15704.41 [#/sec]
```

Comment: Nice, similar to my own async/multiplexing but still different from my threading one, since there are no well.. threads ;p.

I did port the first code example you gave to a threaded and multiplexing one, and i get the same error, im thinking there's something wierd going on between thread and select

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@tomcat.apache.org/msg22589.html) on backlog on tomcat / java which gives an interesting insight in the backlog:

> for example, if all threads are busy
>   in java handling requests, the kernel
>   will handle SYN and TCP handshakes
>   until its backlog is full. when the
>   backlog is full, it will simply drop
>   future SYN requests. it will not send
>   a RST, ie causing "Connection refused"
>   on the client, instead the client will
>   assume the package was lost and
>   retransmit the SYN. hopefully, the
>   backlog queue will have cleared up by
>   then.

As I interpret it, by asking ab to create more simultaneous connection than your
socket is configured to handle packets get dropped, not refused, and I do not know
how ab handles that. It may be that it retransmits the SYN, but possibly after waiting
a while. This may even be specced somewhere (TCP protocol?).

As said, I do not know but I hope this hints at the cause.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're not really getting concurrency.  apparently, when you do socket.accept(), the main thread doesn't go immediately back to waiting for the next connection.  maybe your connection-handling thread is only python code, so you're getting sequentialized by the SIL (single interpreder lock).

if there's not heavy communications between threads, better use a multi-process scheme (with a pool of pre-spawned processes, of course)

Comment: Javier: I tried a multi-process scheme, but I had trouble passing the FD of the accepted connections over to the worker processes (in python atleast)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ran the code on a totally different server - (a vps I got at slicehost), not a single problem (everything works as expected) so honestly I think it's something wrong with my laptop now ;p

Thanks for everyones help though!